# JS Arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

The following code works:

```
.then(jsonResponse => {
            if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
            }
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => (
                {
                    id: track.id,
                    name: track.name,
                    artists: track.artists[0],
                    album: track.album.name,
                    uri: track.uri
                }
            ))
})
```

Why are we using .map(track => (…)) and not .map(track => {…}) as usually with arrow functions?

Comment: Because it's ambiguous whether you are returning an object or defining a block-scope. When you return an object without a `return` statement, you need to enclose it in parens...

Comment: If we don't use `{}`, then arrow function only accepts one expression after `=>`. If we want our expression to expand on more than 1 lines (usually if expression is too long), then we wrap it in `()`.